# Issue with INSERT into table

Tags: postgresql, go

I have successfully established connection with Postgres and GoLang but whenever I insert data in to the table it throws an error of not finding the table

Go Code

```
const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "root"
    dbname   = "test"
)

func main() {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Connection Success")

    sqlStatement := `
INSERT INTO users (id, age, first_name, last_name, email)  
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)  
RETURNING id`
    id := 0
    err = db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, 30, 26, "firstname", "lastname", "Calhoun@mail.com").Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

The ouput I get in console is

```
yashkumar@atri-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/Documents/Feb2.18/src$ go run dbin.go
Connection Success
panic: pq: relation "users" does not exist

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/yashkumar/Documents/Feb2.18/src/dbin.go:40 +0x6be
exit status 2
```

My postgres table name

```
postgres=# \dt
         List of relations
 Schema | Name  | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------+-------+----------
 public | users | table | postgres
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: I have followed this article https://www.calhoun.io/inserting-records-into-a-postgresql-database-with-gos-database-sql-package/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you connect to database **test**

```
dbname   = "test"
```

and you have table in database **postgres**

```
postgres=# \dt
         List of relations
 Schema | Name  | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------+-------+----------
 public | users | table | postgres
(1 row)
```